# Facebook App Not Displayed Insecure Content Message In Chrome

Tags: facebook, ssl

I've been trying to get to bottom of this problem for a few hours but I can't seem to fix it, I've seen other questions similar to this and tried to use those to implement a fix for my problem but to no avail.

I've built a facebook contest canvas app which displays fine independantely but when I link it to a facebook page (as a link to a new contest) chrome no longer displays is and gives the following warning:

The page at 'https://www.facebook.com/contest/app_xxxxxxxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://mydomain.com/': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

I've learned partly by trawling this site that the chrome security is fussier, and the app loads correctly, without errors in FireFox and IE but I can't find any resources that are loaded from a non https source.

I have been through with firebug checking in the net tab and checked that all of the loaded resources are using https (the png images, the jpg images, the css files and the jquery js files which are all hosted on the same server that has the certificate), I have even tried hosting the transitional dtd doc itself but nothing seems to make the warning go away and the app display correctly.

In the other similar questions it seems that there are either resources sourced from non-https sources or there are ssl switches used in the javascript library for facebook passed before the fb init.

The problem is that I am using only the php sdk not the js one (although I am using version 1.9 of jquery, hosted on my server) and I could find no similar ssl specific settings there.

If someone could give me a tip about how I could investigate further, what I might be missing or is familiar with this issue I'd be interested to hear about it.

Thanks a lot.

David

Comment: I've been trying to narrow this down a bit and I've deleted all the code from the page and replaced it with <html>Hello World</html> and the error still exists, very strange

Comment: When making code changes to try and solve this I noticed that the Facebook cache does not seem to be clearing, after more searching I've found that using the Open Graph Object Debugger may clear the cache. Using this tool I can now see the following additional errors and I'm wondering if these are related, here are the error messages:

Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed:
Facebook URL : Facebook URLs cannot be crawled

Errors That Must Be Fixed:
Missing Required Property : The 'og:type' property is required, but not present

I'm trying to resolve these errors but is it likely these are related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution!

In the facebook app settings, if the page tab url is specific to a page e.g. https://www.mydomain.com/index.php, chrome doesn't complain with the insecure content message but if you reference a directory the error is propogated. I found this confusing since the 'canvas' urls need to be directories.

I hope this answer will save someone a few hours! :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion and unfortunately, it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook requires the app to come from https:// you need an ssl certificate on your server and to enable ssl. in the Facebook app settings change secure url to https://mydomain.com url

I did have a similar issue recently (but it only caused issues on IE10) and I resolved that by adding P3P header

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT');
```

Comment: The problem does not exist in IE and all the resources that I can see are already loaded in https